# python: remove values from dict based on another dict values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dict of lists, `x` and `y`. With `x` dict being the slave dict having list of values with indices `0,1 ..` and `y` dict being the master dict, which I need to remove the values from (the one in `x` dict`):

For example:

```
x = { 
        '11': { 
           0: [{'chan_id': '859',
           'brod_id': '596'}],
           
           1: [{'brod_id': '434',
           'restaurant_id': '343'},
           {'chan_id': '545',
           'brod_id': '57'}]
        }
   }
    
y = {"11": 
            [{"brod_id": "169", "chan_id": "209"},
             {'chan_id': '859', 'brod_id': '596'},
             {'chan_id': '545', 'brod_id': '57'}],
    "22": 
            [{"brod_id": "232", "chan_id": "454"},
             {'chan_id': '343', 'brod_id': '55'}]
    }
```

Desired result:

```
filtered_data(x,y,0)  # removing only the `0` indices values of `x` dict from `y` dict
print(y)


y = {"11": 
            [{"brod_id": "169", "chan_id": "209"},
             {'chan_id': '545', 'brod_id': '57'}],
    "22": 
            [{"brod_id": "232", "chan_id": "454"},
             {'chan_id': '343', 'brod_id': '55'}]
    }
```

I tried:

```
def filtered_data(x,y, val):
    for key,val in x.items():
        for k,v in val.items():
            for i,elem in enumerate(v):
                print(i)
                print(elem)  # match the values and delete from y?
            
        
filtered_data(x,y,0)
```

Comment: should work. `if y[k][i] in x[k]: del y[k][i]` to delete see more deletion examples in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-removing-dictionary-from-list-of-dictionaries/

Answer (score 0):

To continue the initial version

```
def filtered_data(x,y, value):
    for key,d in x.items():          
                               
        for i,elem in enumerate(y[key]):

            print(i)
            print(elem) 
            print (d) # match the values and delete from y?
            if elem in d[value]:            
               del y[key][i]
```

Comment: `if y[k][i] in x[k]:                                                                                                                                                        
KeyError: 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if elements in y in x as well using for loops.

```
[y[i].remove(j) for i in y if i in x for j in y[i] if j in sum([x[i][k] for k in x[i]],[])]
```

**Output**

```
{'11': [{'brod_id': '169', 'chan_id': '209'}, {'chan_id': '545', 'brod_id': '57'}],
 '22': [{'brod_id': '232', 'chan_id': '454'}, {'chan_id': '343', 'brod_id': '55'}]}
```